# What does while(i--) mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, while-loop

I'm using swipejs from [swipejs.com](http://swipejs.com), the home page slider uses this logic to highlight the active un-ordered list element and I'd like to know how this **while condition** works.

```
<ul id="bullets">
   <li></li>
    ....
</ul>

var bullets = document.getElementById('bullets').getElementsByTagName('li');

var elem = document.getElementById('mySwipe');

window.mySwipe = Swipe(elem, {

callback: function(index, element) {
    var i = bullets.length;
    while (i--) {
      bullets[i].className = ' ';
    }
    bullets[index].className = 'on';
  }

});
```

Comment: It means that if (i = i - 1) is bigger than 0, continue looping, other wise quit

Comment: `--` is post decrement. So your `while` loop will run and each time, after evaluating `i` it will subtract one from it. When `i` hits zero the expression will be false and the loop will end.

Comment: so far no one's addressed the subtlety of the post-decrement operation. Most people are implying that there won't be an iteration with i = 0, which is incorrect.

Comment: @Tmdean: Since that's the end of the function and `i` isn't used again, it's neither here nor there. Plus, I believe zzzzBov does actually address that.

Comment: @Tmdean, i hope you're not referencing my original answer, as I had the decrement backwards originally.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uTd7D/

Comment: @zzzzBov sorry I realized that your updated answer is correct so I deleted my comment.

Comment: @Tmdean, no problem, just wanted to make sure that I had things written correctly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var i = bullets.length;
while (i--) {
    ...do stuff...
}
```

is essentially equivalent to:

```
var i = bullets.length;
while (true) {
    if (i === 0) {
        i = i - 1;
        break;
    }
    i = i - 1;
    ...do stuff...
}
```

This style of looping tends to be used where performance is super important, as it's slightly faster than iterating indices from `0` to `length-1`, and is relatively straight-forward to implement.

Generally speaking, you shouldn't use it unless you're improving a known bottleneck and have verified that it improves performance in a significant way.

Answer (score 22):

The number `0` is considered falsey in JavaScript, so the while loop will run until it hits 0. You would have to be sure that i is positive to start off with, otherwise you've got an infinite loop.

Comment: @Diodeus: I doubt the difference is noticeable in the vast majority of cases and clearly, judging from the question, it's less readable. Premature optimization and all that.

Comment: @Matt Us hardcore coders likey. Of course, [jQuery n00bs will always be confused on how to add 2 numbers together](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TdrW7.gif).

Comment: @Diodeus I don't see how they can be compared, even. If you changed the `for` loop to be like `for (var i = 100; --i;) {}`, the performance difference probably won't be seen. If you use a `for` loop the normal way, or change the `while` loop to do an extra check (like the `for` loop), then they'll be comparable in performance again.

Comment: @Ian: The equivalent for loop ought to be `for(; i<0; i--)`. I see no difference at all in [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/while-vs-for-backwards)

Comment: @Diodeus A few years ago, that was the case of while loops being faster, but modern browsers clobbered that slowness. Thank you browser engineers!

Comment: @MattBurland (I hope you understand I was agreeing with you and arguing the performance difference wouldn't be seen) Anyways, just wondering, why do you think that's more comparable to the `while` loop? That requires two operations in two places, while mine requires two in one place (not that it exactly matters). I was trying to get away from having two expressions evaluated at different times because that's not what the `while` loop does. And the `while` loop doesn't have an explicit `> 0` expression. And your `i<0` doesn't make sense

Comment: @Ian: Whoops, that was my mistake. Should be `i>0`, obviously.

Comment: @MattBurland, should be `for (i--; i >= 0; i--) {`

Answer (score 5):

It will **first** check `i` value (if not zero), **then** enter loop **after** having decremented `i`.
So, if `i` = 10, loop will be executed with `i` = 9, `i` = 8, .., `i` = 0 and then exit 
(because in last `i--` check, `i` will be already zero from previous loop run)

Comment: This is the most accurate yet succinct answer

Answer (score 1):

`while (i--) { code(); }`
is shorthand for saying `while (i > 0) { code(); i--; }`

Answer (score 0):

It means `var i` is decrementing itself until it reaches 0 (or false in Javascript)

Answer (score 0):

It will iterate thru all integer `i`s backward, because `i--` will decrement `i` (you can do `i++` to increment, go up) (make it go down by 1) so when it reaches 0, it will be considered `false` (all numbers *except 0* are true when converted to bool), thus stopping the loop.

Answer (score 0):

i-- sets the value of i as one less than i.  It is the opposite of i++ which increases I by one.

Answer (score 0):

`i--` or `i++` is shorthand for `i = i - 1` or `i = i + 1`, respectively.

So that while loop works like this: "while `i = i - 1` does not equal 0, `bullets[i].className = ' ';`".

Answer (score 0):

The `i` will decrease (As it the user expect the lenght to be a positive value) each loop.

As a consequence, `i` will be at a certain iteration equal to 0, and 0 is like false in a conditions.